# How to use Cassandra C++ dll in Delphi2010 application?

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, cassandra

When I'm looking for Cassandra drivers for Delphi, I didn't found anywhere. Can we use Cassandra C++ dll in Delphi application? If so, how to use it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some useful info mentioned here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459290/how-to-access-a-cassandra-distributed-database-from-delphi](how-to-access-a-cassandra-distributed-database-from-delphi)

Comment: May be this answer help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557398/using-c-c-dll-in-delphi-2010

Comment: @JafferWilson I doubt that the problem is, "can I call a DLL from Delphi?" The issue is specific to Cassandra. But in any case, this question is off topic since it asks for library recommendations.

Comment: Can you please be more specific regarding what trouble you're having using the DLL?

Comment: @David Heffernan I'm not asking for any library recommendations. I'm asking about how to use Cassandra C++ dll in dll. anyway I changed my question.

Comment: @RobKennedy how to use C++ Class instances in delphi? for example if we fetch rows from Cassandra dabase, it will provide _CassResult_ object.

Comment: There are many questions and tutorials on how to wrap a C++ interface. I doubt that's what you should do though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can we use c++ class instance in delphi?

Comment: Not directly. You need to wrap them. Either in a plain C style interface. Or expose as COM objects. As I said, many examples of this available via web search. This won't be the most effective way to code against Cassandra.

Comment: Your question is now an exact dupe of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496318/how-to-use-c-classes-exported-by-a-dll-in-delphi  and I think you can safely delete this one

Comment: @DavidHeffernan May be this link will give you the answer you require http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm Kindly check and let me know...

Comment: @Jaffer No, that is totally unrelated to this question